# Is it reasonable to think that there was a proto-Ibero-Romance language?

Tags: historia, comparación-de-idiomas, parentesco

Although the idea of proto-language should be qualified and treated with caution, it does seem clear that within the Romance languages Astur-Leonese, Galician-Portuguese and medieval Castilian present the greatest similarities and share a high number of isoglosses.

My question is twofold:

1. The simplest way to explain the coincidences is to resort to a relatively homogeneous (though not free of variation) proto-Ibero-Romance, or is there some alternative model without postulating such a language.
2. If not, is there any phonological or morphological fact that is incompatible with the existence of Proto-Ibero-Romance as an intermediate state between Latin and the modern Ibero-Romance languages?

Answer (score 1):

Las teorías habituales apuntan a que las lenguas proto-ibero-romances se desarrollan en algún momento en los territorios ocupados por los romanos a partir del año 415, de la que derivaría una variedad proto-occidental.

Romance proviene de la expresión "fabulare romanice", "hablar al modo de Roma o Romano", para diferenciarse del mundo y de las lenguas "bárbaras", más tarde la palabra "romance", se utilizará para designar las lenguas derivadas del Latín.

Explicar las coincidencias y diferencias resulta complicado, pues depende de las posturas que toman los distintos autores. En términos generales para los autores más clásicos como Menéndez Pidal, al hablar del arcaísmo de la lengua, en ese proto-ibero-romance que llamamos ahora, aprecia en ella la existencia de una " menor variedad de formas fonéticas y léxicas en España, comparada con Italia y Francia", de esta manera se piensa que el lenguaje Español tuvo que ser muy homogéneo en toda la Península, pobre en variaciones y casi exento de goticismos y aún menos enriquecido de arabismos de lo que en un principio se pensaba.

En la actualidad existen estudios que profundizan en el Mozárabe, el Sefardí o Judeo-Español, el Gótico romance y su relación con el valor germinal del castellano en Castilla, teniendo en cuenta a su vez los elementos del estado idiomático de esa Hispania Visigoda antes de la llegada Árabe, diferenciando entre un Latín culto medieval, el "Latinum circa Romancium" y el romance visigótico. Estas consideraciones llevan a pensar que el "protoiberorromance" no responde a un simple estado intermedio entre un Latín vulgar Hispano y las lenguas actuales, sino que en su evolución concurren variables intercaladas más complejas.

Comment: Very much in agreement, although in my question I already assumed that Proto-Ibero-Romance could not cover the whole peninsula. Catalan and Occitan are clearly not derivable from the same Proto-Ibero-Romance but from Occitan-Romance. The case of Argonese and Ribagorzano is very doubtful, since they originally had more isoglosses in common with Occitan-Romance than with Ibero-Romance. Therefore, if Proto-Ibero-Romance is defined as the ancestor of ALL the Romance languages of the peninsula, it is an ill-defined entity.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo.